# Verifying smart contract on etherscan created through contract factory

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, contract-verification

I deployed contract through contract factory and I'm trying to verify it on etherscan.

After failing attempts I have compared the bytecode of deployed contract from contract factory with the bytycode of the contract which etherscan is creating after verification. 
They are different within first 20 characters.

I'm sure this is not a problem of mismatch of compiler version or different compiler because I can verify the same contract if deployed directly. I use remix to deploy and I have no problem with verifying contracts if deployed directly.

This is not a problem of constructor arguments because I can verify this contract if deployed directly with the same arguments.

Do you think is it possible to verify contract with constructor arguments on etherscan created through contract factory?

What would you suggest otherwise to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted etherscan to help resolve this issue, but all I got back was to talk to programmer about it. They didn't address this issue.